# Gtk3: Show animated GIF from CSS

Tags: css, gtk3

I want to use animated GIF in my Gtk3 application. I know this can be done by assigning `GdkPixbufAnimation` to the `Gtk.Image` component, but this approach requires the animation file name to be referenced directly from the source code.

Is it possible to specify the animation file in CSS, like "normal" background image? I tried to set the animated GIF as `background-image` property of `Gtk.Image` and `Gtk.Label` components, but the image is displayed statically.